# Jenkins - git repo with multiple jobs - build only changed jobs

Tags: jenkins

We have a git repo with multiple projects (A, B, C). Each one has a jenkins job. Now when git notices a change in the repo it will build all of them.

How can I manage it to have like: "build only Job A when there are changes in repo/A"?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use [CloudBees Folder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CloudBees+Folders+Plugin) for your user case.

You have more info here:
[Organizing folders and jobs](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/organizing-jobs-views-instead-folders-just-my-grandma)

Answer (score 0):

The Git Plugin now allows you to specify, under Additional Behaviours:

```
Polling ignores commits in certain paths
```

I would suggest you create a different build job for each branch in your repository structure and exclude the other two.

That said you might want to think about having the different projects in different repositories to enable more granular tagging and branch management.